# Cannot access /wp-admin on a WordPress site installed to a subfolder (mysite.com/blog/wp-admin)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory, multisite, wp-admin

My team and I are running into an odd issue installing a WordPress site in a subfolder, and have decided to turn to the masses as we are all thoroughly stumped.

Here's the overview:

One of our clients would like to migrate their blog site to the same domain/server as their corporate site, but have the blog live in a subfolder as a separate WordPress site. We have successfully migrated the site and its content, and all is working as intended. We are using the same database, with a unique prefix for the blog site. Here is the site:

https://arria22dev.wpengine.com/

And here is the blog site, living at /blog:

https://arria22dev.wpengine.com/blog

As you can see, the site itself is working, however, when we attempt to access the WordPress admin area for the blog site (https://arria22dev.wpengine.com/blog/wp-admin) we receive the following error message:

"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

[image]

I am guessing this has something to do with the wp_users table, .htaccess file at the root, or .htaccess file at the root for the /blog site. HOWEVER, my team and I have not been able to figure this one out and would GREATLY appreciate any help.

We will even send you home-baked cookies for the trouble. Thanks, everyone!

We have attempted to update rewrite conditions in the .htaccess file at the root of the main site.

Comment: Since this is a WPEngine install, I would ask there, since they are ending support for .htaccess as of a few days ago. They have their own WP Engine Web Rules. I would chat with their support team to get this going - since you essentially would need to update the .htaccess of the SUBdirectory site.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, however, their support team is also stumped. I feel like we are so close, as the rest of the site functions as intended

Comment: I was able to access the wp-admin just now.

Comment: @cachem0net on the main site, just curious, is there a "blog" page or anything like a permalink set to that page? In the database for the subsite blog, are the siteurl and home url set to the blog? In wp-config.php (WPE is known to put site values), is there anything set for the siteurls there? I can't recall off the top of my head, but there is a global $wp_siteurl or something similar that sets an array of URLs.